# Array that stores values from two ranges and compares if one cell is blank

Tags: array, vba, excel

This is my first Array in VBA for Excel, but I need some help to optimize the code and try to reduce the number of `If` statements.

The long and short of the code is that it checks to see if there is a Customer name in Column B and checks that against Column A; if there is no value in Column A then  an input box opens to prompt the user to add the CIF number to the specific named range.

Cells B2 through B9 will always have a value, but not every cell B2 through B9 will be used.  Cells A2 through A9 will not always have a value.

Below is the Code:

```
Sub CheckCIF()
    Dim fileArray
    Dim finalRow As Long
    Dim targetCol As Long


    With Sheets("Loan Data")
        finalRow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        targetCol = .Range("A1").EntireRow.Find("CIF #").Column
        fileArray = Array(.Range("B2:B" & finalRow), _
                    .Range(.Cells(2, targetCol), .Cells(finalRow, targetCol)))
    End With

    'fileArray(1)(1) Number in first parenthesis is the column and the number in the second parenthesis is the row

    If fileArray(1)(1) = vbNullString And fileArray(0)(1) <> vbNullString Then
        With Sheets("Loan Data")
            .Range("CIF_1") = InputBox("Please enter the CIF Number for " & vbCrLf & fileArray(0)(1))
        End With
    End If

    If fileArray(1)(2) = vbNullString And fileArray(0)(2) <> vbNullString Then
        With Sheets("Loan Data")
            .Range("CIF_2") = InputBox("Please enter the CIF Number for " & vbCrLf & fileArray(0)(2))
        End With
    End If

    If fileArray(1)(3) = vbNullString And fileArray(0)(3) <> vbNullString Then
        With Sheets("Loan Data")
            .Range("CIF_3") = InputBox("Please enter the CIF Number for " & vbCrLf & fileArray(0)(3))
        End With
    End If

    If fileArray(1)(4) = vbNullString And fileArray(0)(4) <> vbNullString Then
        With Sheets("Loan Data")
            .Range("CIF_4") = InputBox("Please enter the CIF Number for " & vbCrLf & fileArray(0)(4))
        End With
    End If

    If fileArray(1)(5) = vbNullString And fileArray(0)(5) <> vbNullString Then
        With Sheets("Loan Data")
            .Range("CIF_5") = InputBox("Please enter the CIF Number for " & vbCrLf & fileArray(0)(5))
        End With
    End If

    If fileArray(1)(6) = vbNullString And fileArray(0)(6) <> vbNullString Then
        With Sheets("Loan Data")
            .Range("CIF_6") = InputBox("Please enter the CIF Number for " & vbCrLf & fileArray(0)(6))
        End With
    End If

    If fileArray(1)(7) = vbNullString And fileArray(0)(7) <> vbNullString Then
        With Sheets("Loan Data")
            .Range("CIF_7") = InputBox("Please enter the CIF Number for " & vbCrLf & fileArray(0)(7))
        End With
    End If

    If fileArray(1)(8) = vbNullString And fileArray(0)(8) <> vbNullString Then
        With Sheets("Loan Data")
            .Range("CIF_8") = InputBox("Please enter the CIF Number for " & vbCrLf & fileArray(0)(8))
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this code work as expected? Column A appears to be excluded from the array.

Comment: Yes the code works as expected.  I reference Column A in this line `targetCol = .Range("A1").EntireRow.Find("CIF #").Column` and then in the `fileArray(1)(1)` where the 1 in the first () is column A.

Comment: But doesn't fileArray start from B?

Comment: Yes.  I know its backwards, but it is my first Array ever and I get the expected result.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding. Does the following do something similar? https://pastebin.com/Hi39squf

Comment: I get a subscript out of range on `If fileArray(rowCounter, 2) = vbNullString And fileArray(rowCounter, 1) <> vbNullString Then`

Comment: Never mind :-( I think you can use the same loop idea though.

Comment: I will play around with it and see what I come up with.  Thanks for looking at this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fileArray` variable can be replaced with 2 variables. When looking at fileArray in the locals window, from the IDE menu at the top View>Locals Window, you can see that it's it a Variant/Variant(0 to 1). Expanding that by clicking on the + icon to the left of the variable name it it contains two sub arrays. fileArray(0) and fileArray(1) are both of type Variant/Object/Range. These are distinct areas that should be named respectively. `customerArea` for those in column B and `cifArea` for those in the same column as `targetCol` let you refer to these ranges directly.

Because these variables house information stored vertically, that is X rows tall by 1 column wide, you can reference the rows by `customerArea(checkRow).Value2`. Doing this allows you to write self documenting code. Rather than

```
If fileArray(1)(1) = vbNullString And fileArray(0)(1) <> vbNullString Then
```

You have

```
If customerArea(checkRow).Value2 = vbNullString And cifArea(checkRow).Value2 <> vbNullString Then
```

I'm torn between how to go about checking each of the rows. Mulling it over I decided on extracting the check into a Sub. I added a guard clause, `endRow > customerArea.Rows.Count Or endRow > cifArea.Rows.Count`, that raises an error if the end row exceeds the number of rows in each area that's checked. You **could** also add a guard clauses to ensure that `startRow >= 1`, or ensure that `customerArea.Rows.Count = cifArea.Rows.Count` or any others you deem appropriate, but that I'll leave for you.

Instead of checking each row explicitly I condensed that with a [For...Next statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) and used a descriptive variable `checkRow` to let you know which row you're checking.

```
Private Sub CheckForEmptyCellsIn(ByVal customerArea As Range, ByVal cifArea As Range, ByVal startRow As Long, ByVal endRow As Long)
    Const InputMessage As String = "Please enter the CIF Number for "

    Const InvalidArgument As Long = 5
    If endRow > customerArea.Rows.Count Or endRow > cifArea.Rows.Count Then
        Err.Raise InvalidArgument, "CheckForEmptyCells Sub", "endRow argument exceeded number of rows in"
    End If

    Dim checkRow As Long
    For checkRow = startRow To endRow
        If customerArea(checkRow).Value2 = vbNullString And cifArea(checkRow).Value2 <> vbNullString Then
            customerArea.Parent.Range("CIF_" & checkRow).Value2 = InputBox(InputMessage & vbCrLf & cifArea(1).Value2)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This refactoring leaves you with

```
Public Sub CodeReview()
    Dim loanData As Worksheet
    Set loanData = Worksheets("Loan Data")
    Dim finalRow As Long
    finalRow = loanData.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim targetCol As Long
    targetCol = loanData.Range("A1").EntireRow.Find("CIF #").Column

    CheckForEmptyCellsIn loanData.Range("B2:B" & finalRow), _
                        loanData.Range(loanData.Cells(2, targetCol), loanData.Cells(finalRow, targetCol)), _
                        1, 8
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I did make a change so it would reference the Customer Name and not a specific row.  Changed `If customerArea(checkRow).Value2 = vbNullString And cifArea(checkRow).Value2 <> vbNullString Then
            customerArea.Parent.Range("CIF_" & checkRow).Value2 = InputBox(InputMessage & vbCrLf & cifArea(1).Value2)
        End If` to this `If customerArea(checkRow).Value <> vbNullString And cifArea(checkRow).Value = vbNullString Then
            cifArea.Parent.Range("CIF_" & checkRow).Value = InputBox(InputMessage & vbCrLf & customerArea(checkRow).Value)
        End If`